# Server response header states status code 301 despite correct hostname

Tags: http, http-headers, httprequest, httpresponse

I've made a simple client socket in c that has been mostly successful.

The problem I'm having is my client socket receives a 301 status from, ironically, www.w3.org.

---

Observe, when I send the following GET with my client c socket

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: time.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

I receive

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 12 Nov 2015 08:44:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Last-Modified: Thu, 12 Nov 2015 08:40:48 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=74, must-revalidate
X-nananana: Batcache
Vary: Cookie
X-hacker: If you're reading this, you should visit automattic.com/jobs and apply to join the fun, mention this header.
X-Pingback: http://time.com/xmlrpc.php
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1
Link: <http://ti.me/nACNOw>; rel=shortlink
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-ac: 4.ord _dca
```

---

However, when I send a GET request to www.w3.org.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.w3.org
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

I receive

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-length: 0
Location: http://www.w3.org/
Connection: close
```

When google chrome sends a similar GET to www.w3.org

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.w3.org
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
```

The server responds with

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=600
Content-Length: 39276
Content-Location: Home.html
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 15 Nov 2015 04:40:47 GMT
ETag: "996c-524790d293380;89-3f26bd17a2f00"
Expires: Sun, 15 Nov 2015 04:50:47 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 14 Nov 2015 05:00:14 GMT
P3P: policyref="http://www.w3.org/2014/08/p3p.xml"
Server: Apache/2
TCN: choice
Vary: negotiate,accept
```

---

> Why does my client's GET receive a 301 despite its near equivalence with Chrome's GET?
>
> Do some websites have a strict set of required HTTP header fields?
>
> Is there a bigger picture that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure the 301 redirect you are actually receiving does not include other headers not shown here, such as `Set-Cookie`? It does not make sense for a server to redirect to the same URL being requested unless it wants to add something to the request, either cookies or query string.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm pretty positive that's the whole header. Weird right!?

Comment: @Roecrew Are you absolutely sure you're requesting `www.w3.org` and not simply `w3.org`? Because the latter *does have* a permanent redirect to the `www` prefixed one.

Comment: @aergistal Wow, yep that was the problem. If you'd like to post a short answer I'll give you the rep. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`w3.org` enforces the canonical URL `www.w3.org` with a permanent redirect. Requesting just `w3.org` will result in a HTTP 301. The canonical URL is a matter of preference so it shouldn't be assumed that the non-prefixed URL will always redirect to the `www` prefixed one.